# CKEDITOR inline editor not passing editor value

Tags: php, ajax, ckeditor

I have 3 web pages with the same code within a website.  I am having success with 2 of my 3 pages.  The ckeditor instances update as expected.

I have finally figured out "what the issue is", BUT still don't know how to fix it. It seems that if I type only one line of code and click out of the div (ie. blur event happens) it saves as is expected.  If I hit a hard return and type other text the blur event won't save ANYTHING after the hard return.  Seems to be a bug in this version of CKEDITOR.  As I mentioned, I have 2 other pages with exactly the same code and everything works just fine.

```
<?php 
session_start();
$thisPage = "services";
require('functions.php');
include('header.htm');
?>
<title>Services | Dr. Your Name</title>
<style type="text/javascript">
#cke_body {margin-left:120px;margin-top:30px;width:520px;background-color:gray;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.config.filebrowserBrowseUrl= 'browser/browseAdminUploads.php';
CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'justify';
</script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="header" class="clear">
    <div id="headerContent">
        <?php include ("bannerIcons.php"); ?>
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" title="home" alt=""/></a>
        </div> <!--end logo-->      
        <?php include('mainMenu.php');?>
    </div>
</div> <!--end header-->
<div id="container">    
    <div id="content" class="shadow"><div class="content">
    <div id="colLt"><div class="content">
        <?php
        connect();
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT services FROM contentAreas") or die("nothing found");
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
        if ($_SESSION['username']=='admin'){
            echo "<div id='services' contenteditable='true' onblur='saveServices()'>";
        } else {
            echo "<div id='services'>";         
        }       
        echo $row['services'];
        echo "</div>";?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function saveServices() {
                var data = CKEDITOR.instances.services.getData();
                $.post('saveServices.php', {services:data})     
            }
        </script>
    </div></div>
    <?php include('saveServices.php');?>
    <div id="colRt"><div class="content">
        <div id="serviceBox" class="shadow"><div class="content">
            <p class="big italTxt">one or more testimonials could go here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mel cu atqui perfecto, nec te vero fugit denique, an vel mundi tritani concludaturque.<br><br>Laoreet erroribus eos no. Eu nec maluisset repudiandae. Possit lucilius constituam his cu, quas liber sea an, eum purto errem audire eu. In viris assentior vis, pri iudico dolorem electram ne, ea ius scripta virtute.</p>
        </div></div>
    </div></div><!--end colRt-->
    </div></div><!--end content-->  
<div id="footer">
    <?php include("footer.htm") ?>
</div><!--end footer-->
<div class="clear"></div>
</div><!--end container-->
<div class="clear"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

My file saveServices.php is as follows:

```
<?php
$services=$_POST['services'];
echo "hello<br>";
echo "services: ".$services;
include('functions.php');
connect();
$sql1 = mysql_query("UPDATE contentAreas SET services = '$services'") or die ("Your information has not been posted");
?>
```

Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe this nor do I understand it, but when I changed my div name from "services" to "offers", it worked.  Is services a reserve word?  Could my function name saveServices() be too long?  I would love to hear a concrete explanation about why this has happened.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I upgraded from 4.0.2 standard to 4.2.2 standard.